# How to override HTML5 input number step function? Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keydown, keycode

I want to change the step on the HTML5 number inputs of my webapp. I want 100 by 100 instead 1 by 1.

I have tried this:

```
$("#mynumberinput").keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 38) // Arrow-Up
    {
      $(this).val(parseInt($(this).val() + 100));
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) // Arrow-Down
    {
      $(this).val(parseInt($(this).val() - 100));
    }
});
```

But didn't work. How can I achieve this?

Comment: How about `<input type="number" step="100" id="mynumberinput" />`

Comment: "*But [it] didn't work*" in what way did it not work? How did it go 'wrong'? Were there any error messages? What's your relevant HTML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the `step` property on the element itself:

```html
<input type="number" step="100" />
```

Or if you can't modify the HTML directly, you can do this with jQuery's `attr` method:

```
$("#mynumberinput").attr('step', 100);
```

---

Seems the actual problem is that you want to allow the user to enter a number and *then* have it increase or decrease by 100. The problem with your current code is that you're not converting the values to numbers and thus you're encountering what's known as *string concatenation*. To fix this, simply convert them to numeric values before increasing or decreasing the value:

```js
$('input').on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 38)
    this.value = +this.value + 99;
  else if (e.which === 40)
    this.value = +this.value - 99;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" />
```

Note that I'm using 99 instead of 100. This allows the browser's initial handling of it to also kick in. If your `step` value is not `1`, you'll need to offset this yourself.

Comment: No way! `step="100"` Thanks! I will mark as correct answer!

Comment: I'm speculating (and the question is ridiculously vague), but the OP *may* want to adjust the entered value in increments of 100. For example if you enter `120` and then click the up arrow spinner the value will change to `200` rather than `220`. But apparently not (given his comment above). :)

Comment: To "solve it" you first need to take the time to define the problem you have, and answering the questions I asked of you in the comments to the question. We're not sure what you want, or what your problem specifically is, since you've not explained anything about it. You simply showed us some code and said it "doesn't work" without telling us precisely what it should do. James has taken a guess at your problem, with which you seem to be happy, but if you need 'more' you first need to explain what the problem *is*, and precisely what you want, and need.

Comment: @alessadro I've modified my answer to include the situation David has presented. If that's not what your problem is please clarify what exactly the problem is, what you've tried and what the intended outcome is.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly you fix it! that is! and forgive my bad english x(

Answer (score 1):

I think the input step answer is right, but with regards to the JQuery I think you should have parseInt on just the val, and THEN subtract.

```
$(this).val(parseInt($(this).val()) - 100);
```